Rust optional nullable argument, unset or do nothing
Let's say I have function that accept arguments to update a user like this:
pub struct User {
    pub user_id: Uuid,
    pub nickname: String,
    pub avatar: Option<String>,
}

pub struct UserUpdateProps {
    pub user_id: Uuid,
    pub nickname: Option<String>,
    pub avatar: Option<String>,
}

There is many props and operations like this. Update props are passed around, so you can't go with path call or not call an instance.
For nickname Option<String> works fine, it means if no nickname passed - no change required.
For avatar Option<String> doesn't work, because we can't handle two cases - unset and do nothing.
In javascript undefined would mean do nothing, null unset value.
What is the idiomatic way to handle this in rust?

You can have Option<Option<String>>, but the idiomatic way will be to define enum Avatar { Set(String), DoNothing } and use Option<Avatar>.

@ChayimFriedman Option<Option<String>> is workable, but a bit ugly

I see nothing wrong with Option<Option<String>>. If you pass None, you don't set; if you pass Some(x) you set it to x. That x is also an Option is sort of irrelevant.

Based on @Chayim Friedman suggestion, general usage enum seems the best way.
#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord, Debug, Hash)]
pub enum ValueOrNull<T> {
    Undefined,
    Null,
    Value(T),
}
impl<T> Default for ValueOrNull<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::Undefined
    }
}


One way to do this would be a custom enum which you then use as an argument to the update function:
pub enum AvatarUpdate {
    DoNothing,
    Unset,
    SetTo(String),
}

But if you ask me, if your update parameters are all optional, that sounds to me like you might want a couple of single-purpose update functions rather than one function with a lot of options:
impl User {
    // consuming self and returning a new one makes the methods easy to chain
    pub fn with_nickname(self, new_name: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            nickname: new_name,
            ..self
        }
    }

    // call with `None` to unset avatar; do not call at all if you don't want to change it
    pub fn with_avatar(self, new_avatar: Option<String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            avatar: new_avatar,
            ..self
        }
    }
}

let user1 = User {
    user_id: Uuid::new_v4(),
    nickname: "User1".to_string(),
    avatar: Some("cool_avatar".to_string()),
};

// I assume your `User` type implements `Clone`. If it doesn't, you have
// to either consume your original user or let your `with_x` methods take
// `&mut self` and return `&mut Self` instead
let user2 = user1.clone()
                .with_nickname("User2".to_string())
                .with_avatar(Some("less_cool_avatar".to_string()));

let user3 = user1.clone()
                .with_nickname("User3".to_string())
                .with_avatar(None);

This also allows you to use the builder pattern to construct your users if you want:
// using the `From` trait for implementing the constructor for the base `User` 
// here as an example because you seem to require at least a nickname.
// You could also implement `Default::default()`, if you have a sensible default
// nickname in mind. (You can technically also just derive `Default` for `User`
// but that gives you all zeros as the default `Uuid`. Implementing `Default`
// by hand gives you the option to assign a new `Uuid` for each `User`).
impl From<String> for User {
    fn from(value: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            user_id: Uuid::new_v4(),
            nickname: value,
            avatar: None,
        }
    }
}

let user1 = User::from("User1".to_string())
                .with_avatar(Some("cool_avatar".to_string()));


I need to pass this props around through services, so second options doesn't work for me.
First option also not very friendly as I have 1000+ props to update and creating a enum for each is ....

@ZiiMakc You can create a generic enum.

@ChayimFriedman good idea, basically Optional but with different name.
